# Magento 2 Display Price Exclusive Tax

Tags: magento2, price, tax, magento2.2.3

> Magento/catalog/product/price/amount/default.phtml

I have override above `default.phtml` file after that i couldn't able to display exclusive tax on product view page as well as category list page in Magento 2.

I have also set price display setting tax inclusive, exclusive both.

```
    <layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
                <item name="default_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Module::catalog/product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="special_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/special_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/tier_prices.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="configured_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\ConfiguredPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/configured_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <!--<item name="adjustments" xsi:type="array"></item>-->
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</layout>
```

My Module `default.phtml`

> Magento/catalog/product/price/amount/default.phtml

Even if i had copy this `default.phtml` file code to my module file but still its not working at all. Take a look at this screenshot.
http://prntscr.com/jl2a6r

The actual output i want.
http://prntscr.com/jl2b1r

Thanks in advanced :)

Comment: Did you refered https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/tax/display-settings.html this document ? this can be achieved by simple configuration.

Comment: Thanks for reply but now i got solution.

Comment: You can share your solution here  so it might be helpful to others as well.